# Portable way of counting milliseconds in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, time, portability

Is there any portable (Windows & Linux) way of counting how many milliseconds elapsed between two calls ?

Basically, I want to achieve the same functionnality than the `StopWatch` class of `.NET`. (for those who already used it)

In a perfect world, I would have used `boost::date_time` but that's not an option here due to some silly rules I'm enforced to respect.

For those who better read code, this is what I'd like to achieve.

```
Timer timer;

timer.start();
// Some instructions here
timer.stop();

// Print out the elapsed time
std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << timer.milliseconds() << "ms" << std::endl;
```

So, if there is a portable (set of) function(s) that can help me implement the `Timer` class, what is it ? If there is no such function, what Windows & Linux API should I use to achieve this functionnality ? (using `#ifdef WINDOWS`-like macros)

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux (and generally in POSIX), you can use `gettimeofday` function, which returns number of microseconds since the Epoch. On Windows, there is `GetTickCount` function, that return number of milliseconds since the system was started.

Comment: `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` is preferable for measuring elapsed times, since it won't be affected by changes to the system clock.

Comment: As far as I know `clock_gettime` is not implemented on mac, which might disqualify it for some portable applications.

Answer (score 1):

[clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/) (in Time.h) returns a value which increases `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` every second, commonly 1000.

Comment: `clock()` counts CPU time, not wallclock time.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, use the High Performance Timer, it's a doddle.

```
LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
LARGE_INTEGER one;
LARGE_INTEGER two;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&one);
// something
QueryPerformanceCounter(&two);
std::cout << (((double)two.QuadPart - (double)one.QuadPart) / (double)frequency.QuadPart) * (double)1000;
```

In theory, this can go up to per-clock-cycle accuracy, depending on the CPU in question.

Comment: But ereOn is asking for a portable solution, this is Windows specific

Comment: If there is no such function, what Windows & Linux API should I use to achieve this functionnality ? (using #ifdef WINDOWS-like macros)

Comment: This isn't a good solution in these multi-core CPU days no matter what - the HPT can differ per core in a system, and if your thread ends up switching between cores, you're toast: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Hmm. I've seen that, but I've never actually heard of or observed any such. The MSDN specifically says that this only happens due to BIOS or HAL bugs, and if those are bugged, there's nothing you can depend on.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for this task (Boost license)
Where ptime is class that represents time in seconds + nanoseconds `ptime(int sec,int nano)`

And ptime::microseconds create sec/nano pair from posix time microseconds.

It is quite easy to rewrite it for your needs and write such class.

```
ptime ptime::now()
{
    #ifndef BOOSTER_WIN_NATIVE
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv,0);
    return ptime(tv.tv_sec,tv.tv_usec * 1000);
    #else
    FILETIME ft;
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
    unsigned long long tt = ft.dwHighDateTime;
    tt <<=32;
    tt |= ft.dwLowDateTime;
    tt /=10;
    tt -= 11644473600000000ULL;
    return ptime(ptime::microseconds(tt));
    #endif
}
```

And there is no portable C++ function for this...